# Regex to exclude spaces from the phone number

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I've been trying to make a regex for the phone number validation.

It should take a string of minimum 10 digits with "+" symbol.

Here it is:
`^(?=.*[0-9]).{10,}$`

However, it still lets through spaces in the start/middle/end.

Is it possible to make something like `+415555556` go through, but not something like    `+415555556` or `+415555556`

Thank a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex lets through more than just spaces.

Here's a regex that fits the criteria "Starts with a + followed by 10 or more digits and nothing else"

`/^\+[0-9]{10,}$/`

Comment: still lets through the spaces, unfortunately

Comment: @elio_90 This pattern can not match spaces. If it does, can you update the question with the code that you are using?